# when one card is deleted from RecyclerView one more card disappears along with it

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I am having trouble debugging a recycler view issue. Here I am trying to delete an item from recycler view using the following method:

1. when I click on the card (one that is to be deleted), it will store the title of a card in shared preference. (so that in future when I open the app I will know what cards are not to be displayed)
2. Then I am calling a method which checks if the title in shared preference matches the title of the card and make ArrayList consisting of cards which are not present in shared preference.
3. Now I am using this ArrayList to fill cards using **notifyDataSetChanged**

My code is as Follows.

**Adapter**.

```
class LocalAdapter(var localCardsInfo : ArrayList<LocalModel>?,var fragment: LocalListingFragment) : RecyclerView.Adapter<LocalHolder>() {

    fun refreshDataOnOrientationChange(mLocalCards : ArrayList<LocalModel>?){
        if (localCardsInfo!!.size>0)
            localCardsInfo!!.clear()
        localCardsInfo = mLocalCards
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return localCardsInfo!!.size
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: LocalHolder, position: Int) {
        if (localCardsInfo!=null)
            holder.updateUI(holder.adapterPosition,localCardsInfo!![holder.adapterPosition])
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): LocalHolder {
        val card_a : View = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.card_local_a,parent,false)
        return LocalHolder(card_a,fragment)
    }

}
```

ViewHolder

```
class LocalHolder(itemView : View,val fragment: LocalListingFragment) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView),OpenedLayoutManagerLocal{
    fun updateUI(position : Int , localModel: LocalModel){
        moveButton.setOnClickListener({
            archived()
        })

    private fun archived(){
    ALL_STATIC_CONSTANTS_AND_METHODS.addToArchive(fragment.activity!!,model!!.roomName,model!!.deviceName)
    itemView.archiveLayout.visibility = View.GONE
    itemView.elevateLayoutLocal.visibility = View.GONE

    fragment.mAdapter!!.refreshDataOnOrientationChange(ArrayList(LocalDataService.ourInstance.getNonArchivedItems(fragment.activity!!)))
}
```

For example, if I have six item in recycler view and when I delete one I can see 5 items on the list while debugging, even onbind is called 5 times but only 4 items are displayed.
I tried my best to debug it yet failed to find a solution and I can't think about what to do next. I tried notifyItemRemoved and notifyItemRangeInserted also but still, I am facing the same issue. It would be a great help if someone can suggest a possible cause of such issue.
Thank you.

**Edits:**
I just experimented by adding dummy button in fragment where recycler view is placed. An to my surprise if I delete element here just element at that position gets deleted and there is no case of disappearing items. So it seems like problem happens when I delete an item from view holder. So I guess I got the cause of the error but can't think of a way to implement it because the original button is in the card so I am forced to use delete procedure inside view holder. Please do suggest if you have any suggestions. Code that I added in fragment is as follow:

```
    v!!.findViewById<Button>(R.id.delete_button).setOnClickListener({
        try {
            val model = LocalDataService.ourInstance.getNonArchivedItems(activity!!)[0]
            ALL_STATIC_CONSTANTS_AND_METHODS.addToArchive(activity!!,model.roomName,model.deviceName)
            mAdapter!!.refreshDataOnOrientationChange(ArrayList(LocalDataService.ourInstance.getNonArchivedItems(activity!!)))
        }catch (e : Throwable){}
    })
```

Here on this new dummy button click, it deletes the first item in the list gets deleted while on clicking the button on RecyclerView card it deletes one item and then one more item gets disappeared.

Comment: why are you storing the item to be deleted in stored preference why not delete it from the list, you used to populate the recyclerview?

Comment: because I want to show them in archive fragment so that user may restore them if they wish @war_Hero

Comment: ok, share the code where you actually delete it

Comment: In `onBindViewHolder` you use `holder.adapterPosition`. is this for reason? though, it should be replaced with `position` input variable.

Comment: @war_Hero if you want that code then no problem I will post it but while debugging I seen when I delete the item it returns a list of remaining element properly. Every time I delete one item, one more disappears. when I delete next item I can see all previously deleted items in the list but they are not displayed. So I doubt if there is any problem with that part. Reason for me to hesitate is that it has lots of unnecessary stuff like condition checks. But if you still want it, then I will definitely post that piece of code.

Comment: @war_Hero please see edits in the main questions. Even after reading it if you still want the code where I am deleting item then I will post it.

Comment: @Maxim yep, I previously did use position. But when I was debugging this problem I found some suggestion in some of stack overflow questions and one of them was to use posiition in place of holder.adapterPosition. Anyways I had this issue before changing from position to holder.adapterPosition and now just to verify it I changed holder.adapterPosition to position but results were no different. I made few edits to question to add more information about the issue. Please do check that and If have any suggestion or know the cause of error then please do share in coments ore answers section.

Comment: are you calling notifyDataSetChanged, or some other method to inform the adapter that the data is changed, also are you sorting in a particular way before you populate the adapter,

Comment: @war_Hero As you can see in adapter I have **refreshDataOnOrientationChange** method that was originally designed to deal with issues that arise after a change in orientation. Well, it contains just updating of the list and then as you can see it is calling notifyDataSetChanged. So by calling **refreshDataOnOrientationChange** I am indirectly calling notifyDataSetChanged. Code for  **refreshDataOnOrientationChange** is in Adapter part you can see it. It is just calling notifyDataSetChanged.

Comment: @MandarSadye I'm facing the exact same issue right now. This is something to do with the Recyclerview animation. If I set an animator on recyclerview explicitly and try removing a card by swiping it off, it works. Haven't exactly found a solution, more like a hack. Let me know if something worked for you. In my case, an item below the one that I swipe and delete,disappears.

Comment: @happyvirus I got the solution but right now I don't remember exactly how I solved it. Do one thing, delete the last card and let me know the result. I think in my case When I deleted the first card the index changed so when I deleted the second one the card which I swiped went out of the window while the next card got deleted because of change in the index. Let me know if this works.

Comment: @MandarSadye Thanks for your response. Deleting the last item by swiping it off works as expected and doesn't mess up anything. I found the problem is that somehow when I delete any item that is NOT the last, the item below it sets its visibility to INVISIBLE since I do see it in Layout Inspector and it does take up space, so now there's always one item that I can't see, taking up space. I don't set the animator explicitly anymore, but have something like item.setvisibility(VISIBLE) at the top and it works. I would definitely love to know why it happens though.

Comment: @happyvirus I don't have access to the code but in my case when I was swiping a card, I deleted the card at the index. For example, let's say I have 5 cards, I delete 2nd card so now 3rd card is actually second. when I swiped 3rd card it returned me 3 instead of 2 because that is the index assigned to it when the recycler view was first displayed. So instead of removing 3rd card(currently 2nd), 4th card(currently 3rd) was removed. See if the same thing happens in your code. There is some method to refresh recycler view content, I don't remember the exact method.